# Fischer: 1. e4 "Best by test"

Tags: opening, fischer

Fischer famously scribbled "best by test" on one of his score sheets after playing `1. e4`.

Yet when I look at [chess.com's database of games](http://www.chess.com/explorer/), `1. d4` yields a larger win %age for while than does `1. e4`.

Was Fischer wrong?  If not, what changed to make this so?

Comment: Best is 1.Na3. It wins 60% of games. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the difference is only .3% at master level games on chess.com's db, I think Fischer was referring to his own personal results.

A search on chess tempo for Fischer's games reveals that this is the case:
http://chesstempo.com/gamedb/player/239563

- e4 (51.3% win)
- d4 (15.4% win)

**update**: The statistics above are skewed because Fischer never played d4 as white. See comments. Still, my initial point is valid. It was his preferred opening. I don't think .3% makes him wrong.

Comment: Those numbers include all of Fischer's games - both black and white.  Fischer hardly ever played 1.d4, so the reason that 1.d4 scores so lowly is that most of those games featured Fischer playing black.

Comment: Ah. Good point.

Comment: In fact, there's only one game where he played 1. d4 as white in that database, and it was a draw.

Comment: Also, referring to the chesstempo database, white's `1. e4` wins a tiny amount more, but black loses 3% more often.  Just an observation.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Do you mean black wins 3% less? I.e. that there are more draws with e4 than with d4? Yes, the correct "scoring" percentage for a move is wins+(draws/2), not just wins. (All scaled to total games of course.)